# Computing matrix density (sparsity) in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, tensorflow

I need to compute the density (sparsity) of a tensor in Tensorflow.
I am using the MNIST Neural Net Tensorbench example in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html.

I have inserted this code snippet into the sample code (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py) to compute the sparsity (in my case I would just settle for the number of 0s) in the tensor.

In this example there are two tensors: `hidden1` being `784 x 500` and `y` being `500 x 10`.

```
def tf_count(t):
  elements_equal_to_value = tf.equal(t, 0)
  count = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(elements_equal_to_value, tf.int32))
  return count
```

I then print it out during the run with the following statements

```
print ('Sparsity of hidden1: ', tf_count(hidden1))
print ('Sparsity of y: ', tf_count(y))
```

I get the following

```
Sparsity of hidden1:  Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Sparsity of y:  Tensor("Sum_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Which progressively increases as a Neural Net iterates up to:

```
Sparsity of hidden1:  Tensor("Sum_18:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Sparsity of y:  Tensor("Sum_19:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

How do I just get a scalar count of the 0s in each tensor?

Answer (score 4):

Probably late for the person that originally wanted an answer, but an easy way to measure sparsity in tensorflow is [tf.nn.zero_fraction](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/zero_fraction), such as:

```
tf.summary.scalar(tensor_name + '/sparsity', tf.nn.zero_fraction(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use ops from the `tensorflow` (`tf`) package, you're defining operations in the computational graph that have to be placed on a device and executed into a session.

So, every time you call your python function `tf_count` you're defining a new operation into the computation graph: that's why the number, next to the op name, increases.

If you want a python value, you have to execute the operation and fetch the result.

So:

```
#first define your operation:
def tf_count(t):
  elements_equal_to_value = tf.equal(t, 0)
  count = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(elements_equal_to_value, tf.int32))
  return count

# then define your model (your input placeholders, the model architecture ecc...)
#
# than start a Session and run the operation into the graph
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  sparsity_of_h1 = sess.run(tf_count(hidden1))
  print ('Sparsity of hidden1: ', sparsity_of_h1)
```